# PHP & Yii buttons implementation

Tags: php, button, controller, yii2, action

I need to implement a button created in a view. In other programming languages this is very easy: your button has an ID so you can make a reference to it in a controller to implement its action. But in PHP I see like there are some predefined buttons (ex, submitbutton) and I don't understand how can you link an action with a button.

If someone could help me it would be very nice!

Comment: could be you need  a guide for Yii2  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html

Comment: show us the code and what you're trying to do so we can help

Answer (score 0):

First you create an Action in your controller and then in your view try this:

```
<?= Html::a('YourFormName', ['yourControllerName/yourActionName'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In an ActiveForm

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Button caption', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for submit button

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Button Name',['class'=>'btn btn-success'])?>
```

if you want to make button from link here is the code

```
<?= Html:a('Caption',['controller/action'],['class'=>'btn btn-success'])?>
```

if you want to pass some query string in link the her is the code

```
<?= Html::a('caption',['controller/action','id'=>$model->id],['class'=>'btn btn-success'])?>
```